# Globally defined functions converge to function with branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, riemann-surfaces

Consider the class of meromorphic functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given explicitly by

\begin{equation}
f_n(z)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{a=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-a/n}\ .
\end{equation}

For finite $n$, this function is a globally defined function with $n$ simple poles. However, if I take the limit $n\to\infty$ this sum reduces to a Riemann integral, and we have

\begin{equation}
f(z)\equiv\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{z-u}=\log\frac{z}{z-1}\ ,
\end{equation}

which has a branch cut between $z=0$ and $z=1$, and a the composition $f\circ\gamma$ of any closed path $\gamma:I\to\mathbb{C}$ encircling $z=0$ or $z=1$ picks up a monodromy, namely $f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))=2\pi n$ for some $n$.

How does this work? We start with a class of functions all of which have vanishing monodromy around any point, and end up with a function only globally defined on an infinitely-sheeted Riemann surface. I kind of see how infinitely many poles can "coalesce" into a branch cut, but the origin of the monodromy is surprising. Also, is there a general way to find what kind of branch cut will pop out of a limit like this? Could I take a limit of globally defined functions and end up with a limit that has a $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ branch cut?

Comment: The poles are located beteen $0$ and $1$.  Heuristically, as $n\to \infty$ the poles "cover" the interval $(0,1]$.

Comment: @MarkViola I get that, but the emergence of a nonzero monodromy is still very surprising

Comment: For fixed $n$ and any rectifiable closed contour $C$ with winging number $1$ around the interval $[0,1]$, $\oint_C f_n(z)\,dz=2\pi i $.  And for such a $C$, what is $\oint_C f(z)\,dz$?